# Trying to get keys from a dictionary into a class for exploration game

Tags: python, dictionary, keyword-argument

I am having an issue with getting the key from the value of a dictionary into my class. So far I am able to get the values of what I want but can't seem to also obtain the key from where they come from. I think it is because of the way the class is instantiated. I am simply passing the key as the argument but I cannot seem to save the key.

There are constraints to this project. I cannot change the way that the rooms are linked to one another or the methods. There are three files right now that I am working with to try to solve this problem.

```
   #I am using this to get the room set to the player
    class Player:
        def __init__(self, room, **kwargs):
            self.room = room
            self.key = str(kwargs)

        def getRoom(self):
            return self.room, self.key
```

so as you can see this is a simple class. I have tried using **kwargs here to obtain what is being passed in, although I may not understand how that works correctly and fully. I have sifted through documentation but can't seem to find an answer that makes sense to me. On to the others

```
#Again a simple class
class Room:
    def __init__(self, name, desc):
        self.name = name
        self.desc = desc
```

Finally, where the magic is happening:

```
from room import Room
from player import Player
# Declare all the rooms

room = {
    'outside':  Room("Outside Cave Entrance",
                     "North of you, the cave mount beckons"),

    'foyer':    Room("Foyer", """Dim light filters in from the south. Dusty
passages run north and east."""),

    'overlook': Room("Grand Overlook", """A steep cliff appears before you, falling
into the darkness. Ahead to the north, a light flickers in
the distance, but there is no way across the chasm."""),

    'narrow':   Room("Narrow Passage", """The narrow passage bends here from west
to north. The smell of gold permeates the air."""),

    'treasure': Room("Treasure Chamber", """You've found the long-lost treasure
chamber! Sadly, it has already been completely emptied by
earlier adventurers. The only exit is to the south."""),
}

# Link rooms together

room['outside'].n_to = room['foyer']
room['foyer'].s_to = room['outside']
room['foyer'].n_to = room['overlook']
room['foyer'].e_to = room['narrow']
room['overlook'].s_to = room['foyer']
room['narrow'].w_to = room['foyer']
room['narrow'].n_to = room['treasure']
room['treasure'].s_to = room['narrow']

def load_room():
    return player.getRoom()

def update_room(room):
    global player
    player = Player([room])


print("\n*** Welcome to the room explorer")
print("*** You can enter 1, 2, 3, 4 to navigate the corresponding cardinal direction")
print("*** Select 9 to quit\n")

current_room = load_room()
print("this is current room: %s" % (player.key))
print("*** Choose a direction: ***")
user = int(input("[1] North  [2] South   [3] East   [4] West     [9] Quit\n"))

while not user == 9:
    if user == 1:
        if room[current_room.key[0]].n_to:
            update_room(room[str(current_room[0])].n_to)
    elif user == 2: 
        if room[current_room.key[0]].s_to:
            update_room(room[str(current_room[0])].s_to)
    elif user == 2: 
        if room[current_room.key[0]].e_to:
            update_room(room[str(current_room[0])].e_to)
    elif user == 2: 
        if room[current_room.key[0]].w_to:
            update_room(room[str(current_room[0])].w_to)
    else:
        print("\nThere is dead-end, try again")

print(current_room)
print("Please choose to continue...")
user = int(input("[1] North  [2] South   [3] East   [4] West     [9] Quit\n"))
```

I'm sure that there is something that I am overlooking. The logic in the while loop will change once I am able to actually access the key name.

Comment: Have you already read the Python tutorial part about keyword arguments: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments

Comment: I don't understand where you have a problem. Maybe you should provide a reduced example (as properly formatted code in the question).

Comment: Thank you Michael, I have already gone over the keyword-arguments documentation but based on what I have written I think I may be using the wrong tool. My issue is with:  if room[current_room.key[0]].n_to: in the conditional. I need to put the keys from the dict room there but so far I am only able to get what is on the right side of the : for the keys in room. I need the key name itself.

Answer (score 1):

The `Player` object doesn't need a `key` attribute and doesn't need `**kwargs` based on the code I've seen.

The `Room` objects need a `key` attribute which can be initialized to `None` in the `__init__` method (not necessary but good practice).

Regardless if previously initialized the rooms can get their keys after the `room` dictionary was set with:

```
for k, v in room.items():
    v.key = k
```

After that you can e. g. use `current_room.key` to ask for the key of the current room object (as long as it was contained in the `room` dictionary).

Comment: Thank you again Michael, this worked for me without initializing key and I placed in in the  load_room function. I appreciate your response! I didn't know about items() and I will research more in the docs. I appreciate you pointing me towards that